# extract a date from a cell containing text string in excel

Tags: excel, date, extract, formula

**For the Twelve Months Ending Thursday, June 30, 2016**

I have the above text in excel and I need an excel formula to extract ONLY the date **June 30, 2016**. The formulas I've researched were all for numerical dates (i.e. 06/30/2016). Would anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do a substring to find the index of the first comma.  Use that to pull all the RIGHT() text for everything after that index.

Comment: Are all the cells in this format?  Or are there other words before and/or after the date.

Comment: It's always this format but the nth month, day and date changes. For example in July it will say, For the First Month Ending Sunday, July 31, 2016.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand but `DATEVALUE()` works on text.

Comment: thanks durbnpoisn, I followed your suggestion and came up with this formula:  =MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,20)

Comment: @Eileen Do you want to return a date or a text?

Comment: @pnuts No problem, that's fine. I just understood 'The formulas I've researched were all for numerical dates' to mean that she wants a formula to work on text but (and, perhaps, here I assumed) return a date, since she wants to extract a date. :-)

Comment: @Eileen - glad that helped.  Could you please accept my answer.  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

The formula looks like this:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,100)
```

It does a FIND to figure out where the first comma is, and then returns everything  beyond that point.

Comment: Doesn't the OP want a text function to return a date type? Yours returns a text string.

Answer (score 0):

Extracts a Date as a numeric. Then just format it as a date.

```
=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(B20,LEN(B20)-FIND(",",B20)-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MONTH(DATEVALUE(LEFT(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,LEN(A1)),FIND(" ",MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,LEN(A1)-1)))&1)),LEFT(RIGHT(A1,8),2))
```

Hopefully will work for either US or UK locale.